# Why does the error `An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. <Omitted> `occur? Even though I verified that SECRET_KEY_BASE is properly set up in Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, heroku

My ruby ​​version is 2.6.6, my mysql version is 8.0.23, my mysql2 version is 0.5.3, my bundler version is 2.2.21, my rails version is 5.0.7.2, and my Xcode version is 12.5.

I use macOS Big Sur(version 11.4) and the text editor "Atom".

I'm planning to release my Rails application with the URL of HEROKU(example. https://[My APP Name].herokuapp.com).

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku open
```

The following error occured.

```
An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku logs

#<RuntimeError: Missing
 `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `
config/secrets.yml`>
```

I set up two environment variables as below with this command: `$ heroku config:set [ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE NAME]`.

```
$ heroku config:set DATABASE_USERNAME=****
```

```
$ heroku config:set DATABASE_PASSWORD=****
```

My config/secrets.yml file is something like belows.

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ bundle exec rake secret

GENERATED_CODE
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ vi /etc/profile
```

I set up the environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE` as below in Vim editor.

```
-- INSERT --
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  # commands go here
fi
if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
  # commands go here
fi
if [ -d /etc/profile.d -a -f /etc/profile ]; then
  # both are true

fi
if [ -d /etc/profile.d -o -f /etc/profile ]; then
  # at least one is true
fi

export SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE
```

I saved the above `SECRET_KEY_BASE` and ended Vim editor with the two below commands.

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

```
:q!
```

I opened the vim editor again as below with this command:`$ vi /etc/profile`.

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  # commands go here
fi
if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
  # commands go here
fi
if [ -d /etc/profile.d -a -f /etc/profile ]; then
  # both are true

fi
if [ -d /etc/profile.d -o -f /etc/profile ]; then
  # at least one is true
fi

export SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE
```

I verified that the environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE` is properly set up in Linux. Because I ran the two following command.

```
$ printenv | grep SECRET_KEY_BASE

SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE
```

```
$ echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE

GENERATED_CODE
```

I set up the environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE` as below with this command: `$ heroku config:set [ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE NAME]`.

```
$ heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE

Setting SECRET_KEY_BASE and restarting ⬢ [My APP Name]... done, v24
SECRET_KEY_BASE: GENERATED_CODE
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku config

=== [My APP Name] Config Vars
DATABASE_PASSWORD: ****
DATABASE_URL: postgres://****
DATABASE_USERNAME: ****
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA_URL: postgres://****
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK_URL: postgres://****
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
RACK_ENV: production
RAILS_ENV: production
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT: enabled
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: enabled
SECRET_KEY_BASE: ****
```

I checked to see if there're an `/etc/profile.d` directory and an `/etc/profile` file. Because I ran the following command.

```
$ sudo ls -lh /etc/profile

-r--r--r--  1 DATABASE_USERNAME  wheel   599B Aug  2 15:17 /etc/profile
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku open
```

The following error occured.

```
An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku logs

#<RuntimeError: Missing
 `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `
config/secrets.yml`>
```

Why does the error `An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.` occur ? Even though I set up the environment variable of `SECRET_KEY_BASE`.

Comment: I am bit unclear but it appears you did not set the environment variable for "SECRET_KEY_BASE" in heroku only locally. Have you tried `heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE` ?